# Making a div always visible while scrolling through another specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created an image upload widget in my webApp, I want this widget to be visible while filling a specific div being apart of of huge form ( in this div I need to enter some image URLs provided by my widget ), here is the scenario : 
[image: Div Disposition]

To achieve this I did the following :

```
$().ready(function() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );          
    });
});
```

Assuming that `scrollingDiv` is the Id of my widget ( `DIV3` ).

The problem I'm facing is that when I scroll over the `DIV1`, the `scrollingDiv` keeps pushing the bottom, so I can't see the end of my form because of this :
[image: Div blank space]

My question is : How can I disable the scrolling tracking when the `DIV3` collapses with the bottom of my `DIV2` ?

Edit : Analogous case Click [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/az9j990c/)

**PS :** This is My first question on JQuery ... Please don't close the post and give me the chance o improve it if needed ...

Comment: You need to check if `$(window).scrollTop()` is smaller than `$(DIV1).position() + $(DIV1).height()` before you scroll DIV3. If it's larger then it's at the bottom of DIV1 and you should not scroll it any further. Alternatively you could just add `overflow: hidden;` to DIV1 if DIV3 is inside it, but that might interfere with other stuff.

Comment: You could use an already made plugin like : http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ (Never used it, don't know if it's good)

Comment: Could you give a basic demo of this in a snippet including basic js / HTML / CSS?

Comment: Thanks for The Comments That's helping ... 



@misterManSam : I've Edited my post

Comment: @user1743643 : yes because it's not the same CSS, but the Error is there, in JSFiddle I want the widget to stop scrolling when it collapse with the bottom of the first div ... So it's basically the same problem

Comment: As I said, try and find a relation between `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$('#div1').position().top + $('#div1').height() - $scrollingDiv.outerHeight()`. Where `#div1` is DIV1 in your example. (http://jsfiddle.net/ykx7h6ex/)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv : Post it as an answer so I can accept it ...